# Flutter Switch - onChanged not changing with dynamic value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting rows of data in JSON using post request, while changing the status of the table row my checkbox value is not changing.

```
    rows: _Clist.map(
          ((clist) => DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(
                    StatusSwitch(clist.status),
                ),
              ])),
        ).toList(),

   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

    StatusSwitch(SState){  // SState is dynamic value, getting from json post data
       bool SStatus = SState == 1 ? true : false;
       return CupertinoSwitch(
        activeColor: Color(0xFF2ECC71),
        trackColor: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
        value: SStatus,
        onChanged: (bool newValue) {
         setState(() {
          SStatus = newValue;
         });
         print(SStatus);
        },
       );
      }
```

Comment: `SStatus` is a local variable, declared and assigned a value in your `build` method. What would be the expected behavior here?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vtN6ulL_U-5C2VYrTSjDkw2mYUEnakUe/view?usp=sharing check this out

Answer (score 0):

You should move `SStatus` to class visibility level. Now it's a local variable and calculated each time based on `SState` which seems not changed.

2 options:

1. You should change `SState` instead of `SStatus` when new value comes.
2. Move `SStatus` out of method. And declare as class property.

```
bool SStatus = SState == 1 ? true : false;

StatusSwitch(SState){  // SState is dynamic value, getting from json post data as a parameter
       return CupertinoSwitch(
        activeColor: Color(0xFF2ECC71),
        trackColor: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
        value: SStatus,
        onChanged: (bool newValue) {
         setState(() {
          SStatus = newValue;
         });
         print(SStatus);
        },
       );
      }
```

Comment: kindly check this link: 

[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kIhx29gBLb_FDYud7B3305i46SqRin70/view?usp=sharing)

I also want to update the status value with the post request, using API. I want to switch the status 1:4

Comment: it's really hard to read. In your code no difference between classes naming, variables, and properties.
Fix all code style issues and you will find an error;) Beileve me

Comment: video preview:
[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l23h5ruGl_WDdD4GENNFA59hbg5uar2h/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am in a learning process and this is my first project that's why I am working by just following youtube videos, I think that's why my code is not Fixed.

Comment: I just take variable out of the function StatusSwitch and now on a single tap all switches are changing instead of one.

Comment: Check this now: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vtN6ulL_U-5C2VYrTSjDkw2mYUEnakUe/view?usp=sharing